# Charles Proxy Causes Privacy Error

Tags: javascript, facebook, proxy, localhost, charles-proxy

I'm using Charles to proxy in files from localhost to test features of a facebook game.  This was working yesterday, now suddenly turning the proxy on results in a privacy error from Chrome:

"Your connection is not private, NET:ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID".

I get similar messages from Safari and Firefox as well.  Disabling the Mac OSX proxy allows me to load the game again.  Other websites are hit or miss.  For example, Google seems to be affected, but not Amazon.

I'm not sure what to check for in Charles's settings, as there's not a lot of documentation for it (and I don't believe I've changed anything since it was working last).

Comment: It seems the latest version of Chrome on iOS doesn't allow for proxying using Charles (or perhaps anything). It thinks it's a man-in-the-middle attack (which is sort of is, but being performed by me, duh). If anyone figures out a a way to get around it I will ask a question on Stack Overflow and post a link here to that question - please post an answer there (very similar search terms to this question, could be helpful).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Something I had done in Keychain must have wiped out Charles's SSL certificate.  I reinstalled by going to Help -> SSL Proxying -> Install Charles Root Certificate.  Everything seems to work after that.

Comment: If this ^ doesnt work. Open Keychain and lookup for Charles in All items, remove everything charles-related and re-install charles root certificate. If it shows a red X, manually double click it, Trust -> Always trust

Comment: This worked for me. Did you re-install cert first Tom?

Comment: I had to install the cert from within Charles and then set it to trusted in the Keychain and then everything worked fine. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 36):

Open Keychain and look for Charles in Certificates. If it shows a red X, double click it, Trust -> Always Trust

Answer (score 4):

The step by step guice to get this working is as follows:

- Install Charles
- Install Firefox
- Open Charles
- Help > SSL Proxying > Install Charles Root Certificate
- I installed in both "system" and "login".
- Open Keychain Access (Utilities > Keychain Access, assuming on a Mac)
- Search for "Charles"
- Open the two certificates and change all trust levels to "Always Trust".
- Quit Keychain Access, Firefox, and Charles
- Reopen Charles, then firefox.
- Install the Charles FF plugin: Charles > Help > Install FF Plugin
- When installed RESTART FF.
- Enable Charles in FF: Tools > Charles > Enable Charles Proxy
- 

Comment: I don't have anything for Charles in Keychain Access weird

Comment: @raphisama You didn't install certificate. Follow `Help > SSL Proxying > Install Charles Root Certificate`

Answer (score 4):

In Chrome on Windows, you need:

1. Install Charles Root Certificate
2. Save Charles root certificate
3. Open Chrome and find "`Manage certificates`"
4. Install saved certificate in "`Trusted ROOT certificate`" (It's important. If you install in other tabs, it'll not work).
5. Restart Chrome

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :-)) I was wondering why it didn't work.

Comment: If you still have an installed Charles certificate from using the Charles interface for installation before, it will be  in any of the other certificate locations (check internet options > contents). 
It might be used by the application trying to establish a connection instead, at least for me that was the case. I didn't see any specific pattern here though. Deinstalling that certificate should help.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still stuck on this issue. Even after following everything that was mentioned here. I was still getting
`"Your connection is not private, NET:ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID"` error message.

Then I just decided to do a system restart and try again. And thankfully everything was resolved after the restart.

So anyone who is stuck here please do try a system restart after installing the certificate.

Comment: I'm still stuck here... even after a restart. >.<